# Is there a way to create a precise tap area from the image shape?

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, gesture, tap

I am trying to create an interactive U.S. map, but for this to work, each State's hit area will need to be precise based on its shape. Otherwise, the user will trigger other neighboring States.

Attached is the code. I've searched all I could and found nothing. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

struct MapGraphic: View {

```
@State private var stateColor:Color = .white

var body: some View {

    ZStack {

        Image("California")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .colorMultiply(Color("lGrey"))
        .frame(width: 50.45, height: 87.41)

        .onTapGesture {

        switch self.stateColor {
        case .white:
            self.stateColor = .blue
        case .blue:
            self.stateColor = .red
        default:
            self.stateColor = .white
        }

        }.colorMultiply(stateColor)

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things:

1) construct path in rect of image (point by point)

> ```
> extension Path : Shape {
>
>     /// Describes this shape as a path within a rectangular frame of reference.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameter rect: The frame of reference for describing this shape.
>     /// - Returns: A path that describes this shape.
>     public func path(in _: CGRect) -> Path
> ```

2) set that path (which is a Shape) as hit-testing area to your image

> ```
> /// Returns a new view that defines the content shape for
> /// hit-testing `self` as `shape`. `eoFill` defines whether the
> /// shape is interpreted using the even-odd winding number rule or
> /// not.
> @inlinable public func contentShape<S>(_ shape: S, eoFill: Bool = false) -> some View where S : Shape
> ```